# Could I use different service to get the same redis cache?

Tags: redis, docker-compose, spring-data-redis

Excuse me! I have 2 service in docker container that has different IP. They are use the same redis-server. When I use service1 to create redis cache, then I use service2 to get redis cache. but it can't get the redis cache. So could I use different services to get the same redis cache that use the same redis-server?

Comment: Yes you can. Can you please post your `dockerfile` and `dockercompose` files?